# Computing surface of a part of a ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, analytic-geometry

I have the upper half of the ball $\ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R , \ (z \ge 0)$ and the plane $\ z = h $ where $\ 0 < h < R $ .

How do I compute that surface of the ball above the plane? and show it is $\ 2 \pi R(R-h) $

My attempt:

The intersection projection of the plane $\ z = h $ and the ball is $\ x^2 + y^2 = R - h^2 $ hence the area I want to compute is a circle with radius $\ R $ and then subtract from it the circle with radius $\ h $ . Though the answer I get is $\ 2\pi(R-h) $ and not $\ 2\pi *R*(R-h) $

$$\ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R})} R^2 \sin \theta = R^2 \int \sin \theta [cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R})] = R^2 \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R}) \cdot [- \cos \theta]_0^{2\pi} = R^2 \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R}) \cdot (-1 +1) = 0 $$

Comment: The equation of sphere is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$. Also. $2\pi (R-h)$ is a linear function and surface must be a quadratic function.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Thought I'm still confused as to how am I supposed to compute the integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were asked to compute the surface area of a sphere of radius $R$; i.e  of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2 $, the typical approach would be to use spherical coordinates
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
x &= R \sin \theta \cos \phi \\
y &= R \sin \theta \sin \phi \\
z &= R \cos \theta
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
with $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, and $0 \leq \phi \leq 2\pi$. But now you don't want the entire sphere, so how would the limits of integration of integration change? (draw a picture; it's very simple trigonometry).

Edit:

After looking at your work, it seems you are slightly unclear about which variables are being held fixed in integrals, and which are varying. So the integral you want to evaluate is
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{2\pi} \left(\int_0^{\arccos(h/R)} R^2 \sin \theta \, d\theta \right) \, d\phi
\end{equation}
I added the () to make it clear in what order to do things. Evaluate the inner integral first; you should get something which depends only on $R$ and $h$. Then, you can pull those constants out and solve the outer integral

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand I should limit $\ \phi $ but trying to extract the exact value for $\ \phi $ I get $\ 0 < \phi < \cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R}) $ and that doesn't help me.

Comment: @bm1125 yes that's correct; it looks complicated but that is what simplifies the computation at the end. Are you having trouble setting up the integrand/ evaluating the integral?

Comment: Yes. Is it $\ \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{cos^{-1}(\frac{h}{R})} R^2 d \phi d \theta $ ?

Comment: the "change of volume factor" is $R^2 \sin \theta$ not just $R^2$

Comment: Can you show the computation because I just get $\ 0 $ . ?

Comment: if you include your full computation, I can tell you where you went wrong; I believe that is more instructive for learning

Comment: Sure, added to the original answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94112/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-bm1125).